# Multiple WP Query pagination issue with shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I am using a shortcode to call a sample WP Query with pagination:

```
<?php 

$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged,
);

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

everything works okay but the problem is that I am using the shortcode to call this and if I have more than 3 shortcodes and if I go to page 2, all of them go to page two.

How can I modify this so each query is unique and relevant to its own pagination?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "get_query_var" for all three shortcode.

For example for first shortcode.

```
    $paged = ( get_query_var('fpage') ) ? get_query_var('fpage') : 1;

    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged,
);
```

Please set same for all other as (spage and tpage).

You need to set query_var variable from function file.

```
function add_query_vars_filter($vars) {
    $vars[] = "fpage";
    $vars[] = "spage";
    $vars[] = "tpage";

    return $vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter');
```